2024年6月時点では、Amazon SNSを介してAndroid端末にプッシュ通知を送れないのか
お世話になります。
現在、FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging)から取得したデバイストークンを利用し、amazon SNSを介してFlutterアプリへプッシュ通知を送信しようとしております。Flutterアプリの方ではデバイストークンを取得できていることを確認しております。
次にデバイストークンを受け取ったSNSでエンドポイントを作成するためプラットフォームアプリケーションの作成を試みましたが、InvalidParameterのエラーにより作成できないという状況になっております。
こちらの件についてAWSサポートに問い合わせたところ、以下の回答がありました。(2024/06/18)

お調べしたところ、現在 Amazon SNS の FCM プラットフォームアプリケーションについて FCM Legacy API のサーバーキーにのみ対応しており、FCM HTTP v1 API には対応していない状況でございます。
そのためLegacy API のサーバーキーをご利用いただけますと幸いでございます。

現在すでにFireBaseのCloudMessagingの「Cloud Messaging API（レガシー）」は無効になっており、Firebase Cloud Messaging API（V1）しか使えないという認識です。
そのため、SNSではLegacy APIのサーバーキーしか利用できず、且つFCMではもうレガシーAPIは利用できないため、現在SNSを介してAndroid端末にプッシュ通知を送ることはできない、ということでしょうか？
【補足】
以下、プラットフォームアプリケーション作成時の手順となります。
「(AWS)SNS→プッシュ通知→プラットフォームアプリケーションの作成」と進み、認証方法が「トークン」の場合と「キー」の場合の以下両方を試しました。（他項目はデフォルトのままです）
■トークンの場合
・アプリケーション名：(アプリ名)
・プッシュ通知プラットフォーム：Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)
・認証方法：トークン
・Service Json：google-services.json（FireBaseのプロジェクトの設定からダウンロードしたもの）
■キーの場合
・アプリケーション名：(アプリ名)
・プッシュ通知プラットフォーム：Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)
・認証方法：キー
・API キー：（FireBaseのプロジェクトの設定からダウンロードしたgoogle-services.json内のcurrent_key）
どちらの場合も、上記を入力し「プラットフォームアプリケーションの作成」ボタンを押したところ、以下のメッセージが画面下部に表示され、プラットフォームアプリケーションが作成できませんでした。

プラットフォームアプリケーションを作成できませんでした。
エラーコード: InvalidParameter - エラーメッセージ: Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid


2024 年 1 月の更新で、Amazon SNS は FCM HTTP v1 API を使った Android 端末へのプッシュ通知に対応しています: https://aws.amazon.com/jp/about-aws/whats-new/2024/01/amazon-sns-fcm-http-v1-api-mobile-notifications/
私の環境では、サービスアカウントの秘密鍵 JSON ファイルを Firebase コンソールからダウンロードし、それをトークンとして渡す形でプラットフォームアプリケーションを設定でき、かつプッシュ通知が送れると確認しています。
AWS サポートから FCM HTTP V1 API に対応していない旨が返答されたのは謎です。コンソールでの設定も失敗しているとのことなので、ドキュメントと共に聞き返してみるとより詳しい事情が分かるかもしれません。

ご回答ありがとうございます。現在でもFCM HTTP v1 APIによるSNSからのプッシュ通知は可能、と言うことで承知いたしました。今年の１月の段階でFCM HTTP v1 APIでプッシュ通知が送れているとなりますと、「FCM HTTP v1 API には対応していない」というサポートの回答はやはり妙なのかもしれません。引き続き確認してみます。
